# Why does the JSON function in ORACLE does not fetch data when used with a search index and NULL values?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

The problem I face is about the usage of `JSON_VALUE()` function in ORACLE with `null`. I have a table where in column named "JSON_COLUMN" of type BLOB there is a json value which is either `{"foo":"111"}` either `{"notfoo":"111"}` either `{"foo":null}`.

Basically, I've not been able to fetch the rows where the "JSON_COLUMN" column has data with field `foo IS NULL` or field `"foo"="111"` with oracle function `JSON_VALUE()`.

I tried this following query :

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, "$.foo") IS NULL
   OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, "$.foo") = "111"
```

but this does not fetch the row where the json looks like `{"notfoo":"111"}` or `{"foo":null}`.

I also tried each independent side of the OR, each of those works fine. I also tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, "$.foo") IS NULL
   OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, "$.foo") IS NOT NULL
```

and I have the expected results which are all the rows in my table.

Does someone knows why the `JSON_VALUE` function act like this with the OR ?

**EDIT :**

After more investigation, the issue is not related to the 'OR' or related to the fact that we miss the `on error` part. I've been able to reproduce exactly my issue with a minimal database and I missed a point where in my database I've added a search index.

Here is the example where all the results I get are expected, and after the addition of the search index, the results are no more what we expect :

```
CREATE TABLE DUMMY (COLUMN1 BLOB);

ALTER TABLE
    DUMMY
ADD
    CONSTRAINT DUMMY_CHECK_JSON CHECK (COLUMN1 IS JSON);

INSERT INTO
    DUMMY (column1)
VALUES
    ('{"notfoo":"222"}');

INSERT INTO
    DUMMY (column1)
VALUES
    ('{"foo":"111"}');

INSERT INTO
    DUMMY (column1)
VALUES
    ('{"foo":null}');

select
    COLUMN1
from
    DUMMY
where
    JSON_VALUE(COLUMN1, '$.foo') IS NULL
    OR JSON_VALUE(COLUMN1, '$.foo') = '111';

-- ====> 3 results

CREATE SEARCH INDEX IX_CNT_DUMMY ON DUMMY(column1) FOR JSON PARAMETERS(
    '
        DATAGUIDE OFF
        SEARCH_ON TEXT
        SYNC (EVERY "freq=secondly; interval=1")
        OPTIMIZE (EVERY "freq=weekly; byday=SAT")
    '
);

select
    COLUMN1
from
    DUMMY
where
    JSON_VALUE(COLUMN1, '$.foo') IS NULL
    OR JSON_VALUE(COLUMN1, '$.foo') = '111';

-- ====> only 1 result !

select
    COLUMN1
from
    DUMMY
where
    NOT JSON_EXISTS(COLUMN1, '$.foo')
    OR JSON_VALUE(COLUMN1, '$.foo') = '111';

-- SAME, only one result

drop index IX_CNT_DUMMY;

select
    COLUMN1
from
    DUMMY
where
    JSON_VALUE(COLUMN1, '$.foo') IS NULL
    OR JSON_VALUE(COLUMN1, '$.foo') = '111';
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, in Oracle, you use single quotes to delimit paths in JSON_VALUE or string constants. Second, this has nothing to do with OR. Third, depending on what you want, you can specify to the JSON_xxx functions what to do if the key you are looking for does not exist (the 'null on error' or 'error on error' below)

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM (select '{"foo":null}' json_column from dual)
  2  WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo' error on error) IS NULL
  3*    OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo'  error on error) = '111';

    JSON_COLUMN
_______________
{"foo":null}


SQL> SELECT * FROM (select '{"foo":"111"}' json_column from dual)
  2  WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo' error on error) IS NULL
  3*    OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo'  error on error) = '111';
SQL> /

     JSON_COLUMN
________________
{"foo":"111"}

SQL> SELECT * FROM (select '{"notfoo":"111"}' json_column from dual)
  2  WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo' error on error) IS NULL
  3*    OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo'  error on error) = '111';
SQL> /

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT * FROM (select '{"notfoo":"111"}' json_column from dual)
WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo' error on error) IS NULL
   OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo'  error on error) = '111'
Error report -
ORA-40462: JSON path '$.foo' evaluated to no value.

SQL>  SELECT * FROM (select '{"notfoo":"111"}' json_column from dual)
  2  WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo' null on error) IS NULL
  3*    OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo'  ) = '111';
SQL> /

        JSON_COLUMN
___________________
{"notfoo":"111"}

SQL> SELECT * FROM (select '{"notfoo":null}' json_column from dual)
  2  WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo' null on error) IS NULL
  3*    OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo'  ) = '111';
SQL> /

       JSON_COLUMN
__________________
{"notfoo":null}

SQL> SELECT * FROM (select '{"notfoo":null}' json_column from dual)
  2  WHERE JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo' ) IS NULL
  3*    OR JSON_VALUE(JSON_COLUMN, '$.foo'  ) = '111';
SQL> /

       JSON_COLUMN
__________________
{"notfoo":null}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the `null/error on error` syntax. This has fix the results of my query if I put `null on error` for `IS NULL` condition and `error on error` on the `='111' ` condition. For the single quote it was an attention mistake thanks.

Comment: It is finally not the right answer that I needed unfortunately. Actually, specifying the `null on error` is the default behavior for `JSON_VALUE()`. So the query where we fetch all `$.foo` where it is either `null` or `'111'` should work without any `error on error` (like the last query of @gsalem). The weird thing is that if I add `error on error` on the second part of my query (for the `='111'`), The query works, even if it should not. And I don't understand this behavior. I've edited my question to add more context I found on the issue.

Comment: I think the behavior with the index is a bug.

Comment: Probably, my team has raised a ticket at oracle side. I will post the final answer or solution here when we have news.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this behavior is a bug from Oracle. You can find it on the oracle support website : https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=35457454&parent=SrDetailText&sourceId=3-33252210991

No patch exists yet, they will try to fix it. I'll accept this answer when oracle will fix the bug and deploy the patch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).